# How to get a invite from a server your bot is in from a command in discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

here's my current code but when ran it says [object Promise]

```
    client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === prefix + 'invite'){
            //create a invite 
            const invite = client.guilds.cache.get('981948182844039198').channels.cache.first().createInvite({
                maxAge: 0,
                maxUses: 0
            })
            message.channel.send(`${invite}`)
        }
    }
    )
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

According to discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Invite) to get invite link you should use [`Invite.url`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Invite?scrollTo=url) or [`Invite.code`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/Invite?scrollTo=code) to get a code of the invite!